# AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403 in streamlit

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, streamlit

I am getting this error **"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403"** while uploading image on streamlit app.
this is my code [screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMzYW.png)

```
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image

# Title
st.title('Image Viewer')

    #Upload an image
uploaded_image = st.file_uploader("Upload an image", type=["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "webp"])

    # Check the type of the uploaded image
if uploaded_image is not None:
        # Open the image using PIL
        image = Image.open(uploaded_image)
        # Display the image
        st.image(image, use_column_width=True)
```

I checked all the necessary packages is installed along with tried running same project in newly created environment but it didn't solve anything.

Comment: See https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/file-upload-fails-with-error-request-failed-with-status-code-403/27143/23

Answer (score 1):

If you are running it locally try:

> `streamlit run app.py --server.enableXsrfProtection false`